# React Node authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am trying to get the authentication done with react router. I call an endpoint in componentdidmount to see if the user has logged in (I get a 401 response if he has not). If that is the case, I redirect it to login otherwise I let it go to the desired component. However, this does not seem to be working. Any particular fix for this?

Problems: 
1) If the user is not authenticated (I get a 401 back), it still takes me to /profile upon login. 
2)I am getting this error in Node - Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - in that function.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

async componentDidMount() {
    const url = '/getinfo'
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
      });

      const json = await res.json()
      const status = res.status
      if(status === 401) {
        this.props.history.push('/')
      }
    } catch(error) {
    console.log('Error', error)
    }
  }

  render() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>

            <NavigationBar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = '/'
                component = {LandingPage}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/register'
                component = {Register}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/profile' 
                component = {Profile}
              />
              <Route path="*" component = {() => "404 NOT FOUND"}/>
            </Switch>

      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Backend function - Nodejs

```
router.get('/getinfo', checkRedis, (req, res) => {
    res.send('works!');
})

module.exports = {
    checkRedis: function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('called')
        if(!req.session.user) {
            res.sendStatus(401).json({message: 'Session expired'})
        return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You are using try/catch a bit wrongly. When the fetch get's response status like 401(means it is a bad response) it will fail and throw an error. Try putting the redirection in catch block. I hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I don't think fetch will do throw an error on a 401 "The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

I think you're sending a 200 response every time.

```
router.get('/getinfo', checkRedis, (req, res) => {
    res.send('works!');
})
```

Just leave out the anonymous function. Your .get only needs one callback.

```
router.get('/getinfo', checkRedis)
```

Comment: But what if I need to send the user details as a response? I want to check if the 401 is sent, and if it is, then I do not want to continue

Comment: add an else{} after your if{} inside checkRedis and send whatever you want.

Comment: But that is a middleware, and I dont want to send something in that function. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of things that may have caused the issues.

Firstly, please console.log (status) and see if it really shows 401 when use hasn't authenticated. Because I think you have to catch status 401 in catch block as an error like this.

```
 } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.status === 401) {
     ... do something
    }
```

this is how I catch all status except 200 in react and node js app.

secondly,

--- Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, ---

this error message normally occurs when you respond to client twice like this

res.send( something ... ) res.send( something else ... )

sending two responses in one router at once is impossible for express router

so I suggest you to have a deep look at your code to see if there is somewhere you send response but not return the fn after that.

plus, could I ask you why you didn't do next() thing in middleware? 
I think it is necessary to make your   res.send('works!') work.

I hope this helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Axios` here which will throw an error on 4**/5** status.

Example:

```js
axios.get("https://www.google.com/").then(res => res.data)
.catch(e => {
  console.log("error Occured"); 
  console.log(e)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```